# Typescript assign generic type to variable

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

When trying to assign a generic type to `Type<any>`, i cannot get the type constraint correct when i know the type is an angular component.

However directly assigning a component type works.

This works

```
private routeComponent: Type<any>;
public component<TComponent>(): RouteBuilder {
    this.routeComponent = HomeComponent;
    return this;
}
```

This doesnt.

```
private routeComponent: Type<any>;
public component<TComponent>(): RouteBuilder {
    this.routeComponent = TComponent;
    return this;
}
```

It fails with

> error TS2693: 'TComponent' only refers to a type, but is being used as
>   a value here.

How can i make it so my component method accepts only a Component, or if cant do that at least be able to assign the generic type to the `Type<any>` the same as i can if i do it direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are implemented in Typescript using type erasure, so at runtime `TComponent` will not available. You can pass the class as an argument to the function instead :

```
public component<TComponent>(type: Type<TComponent>): RouteBuilder {
    this.routeComponent = type;
    return this;
}
component(HomeComponent);
```

Comment: Excellent! just what i was looking for, thanks very much